# what's the maxGranularity/minGranularity?

Tags: media-source

I'd like to know definition of maxGranularity/minGranularity  at MSE.
When i googling, https://yt-dash-mse-test.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/unit-tests/2017.html?test_type=progressive-test&timestamp=1505692969966
it looks google's mse test page?

Could somebody guide me about 'granularity'?
If there's keyword for that, please tell me.

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

This has more to do with the HTMLMediaElement (`<video>`) than it does MSE.

The media element will have a `timeupdate` event, which is regularly fired as playback occurs.  It allows you to update a text field or something with the current time offset of the media.

This isn't an event that fires every frame... it typically fires 3-5 times a second, and can fire less if the tab isn't active or the browser chooses.

Granularity is just indicating roughly how frequently that event is going to fire, despite having video running at different speeds.  It's a test to make sure that the event is still firing, even if the playback rate is very low or very high.